# Fill textarea from input value in different divs

Tags: javascript, forms, html, input, textarea

i am working on a upload section for my website.
When users want a new application to upload they need to fill out a form where the put the version number etc.

There are 27 different applications wich can be uploaded. for that i have made a while loop

example:

```
<select id="type">
<option value="choose" selected>choose here</option>
<?php

require("Function/applist.php");
while($showtablerow = mysql_fetch_array($showtablequery_result))
{
echo "<option value=".$showtablerow[0].">".$showtablerow[0]."</option>";
}

?>  
</select>   
</div>
<div id="choose" class="add" style="display:none;"></div>


<?php

require("Function/applist.php");
while($showtablerow = mysql_fetch_array($showtablequery_result))
{

    echo "<div class='add' id=".$showtablerow[0]." style='display:none;'><h2 id='amx-label'>".$showtablerow[0]."</h2>
    <div id='formadd' style='opacity:1;'>

    <form name='addamx' id='addamx' method='post'>

        <div id='version' class='uploadform' style='opacity:1;'>
            Version: <input style='opacity:1;' required type='text' name='versie' id='versie' width='3' onchange='process1()' ><br>

        </div>
        <div id='date' class='uploadform' style='opacity:1;'>
            Release Date(yyyy-mm-dd): <input required type='date' style='opacity:1;' size='10' maxlength='10' name='date'  id='date'>

        </div>
    <div id='build' style='opacity:1;'>
            Build By: <input required type='text' style='opacity:1;' size='5' maxlength='25' name='build'  id='build' >


        </div>
        <div id='platform' style='opacity:1;'>
            Platform: <span>32 Bit:</span><input required type='radio' style='opacity:1;' id='platform'  name='platform' value='32bit'>
                  <span>64 Bit:</span><input required type='radio' style='opacity:1;' id='platform'  name='platform' value='63bit'>
        </div>
        <div id='application'>
        <input type='hidden' name='app' value=".$showtablerow[0]." />
        </div>  
        <div id='notes' style='opacity:1;'>
            Release Notes: <textarea id='notess' name='test' onblur='process1()'></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id='uploadfooter' style='opacity:1;'>
            <button type='submit' id='uploadamx' name='uploadamx'>Upload
        </div>  
    </form>


    </div>



</div>";
}
?>
```

In the select box they choose wich application they  want to upload, and depending on that selection they get a form.

In the text area they write their release notes.

I want that when they fill their version number that automatically that version number is filed in in the text area.

i got that kinda working with the following javascript:

```
function process1() {
var appname = document.getElementById('type').value;
var version = document.getElementById('versie').value;
var textvalue = "changes for " + appname + " version " + version;

document.getElementById("notess").value = textvalue;

}
```

the function works only for the first form div
When i try it on the second div that textarea stays empty and the version number from the second div gets inserted in the textarea from the first div

How i can make the function so that the textarea only gets filled with the version number from that form?
Any ideas?

EDIT***

the way AboQutiesh was the good startup, the only adjustment that it needed was
He wrote:
    onblur='process1(".$showtablerow[0].")'
result was onblur='process1(argument)'
This didnt work because the argument needed onblur='process1('argument')'
because it is in a while loop i couldnt just put the '' because it would break up the entire onblure
thansk to a collegea of my who pointed me to the ascii table
SOLUTION:

i changed it to onblur=process1(&#39".$showtablerow[0]."&#39)

(delete the ; at the end of the asccii otherwhise it wouldnt show here properly)
Thanks for the startup AboQutiesh

Comment: You are duplicating your form (with a loop) and all the input fields. Since you are using id's with your form en input fields, and getElementById to retrieve them, it's impossible to determine what is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to provide different ids for each text area like this in php :

```
    <div id='notes' style='opacity:1;'>
        Release Notes: <textarea id='notess_".$showtablerow[0]." name='test' onblur='process1(".$showtablerow[0].")'></textarea>
    </div>
```

and in the js

```
    function process1(appId) {
     var appname = document.getElementById('type').value;
     var version = document.getElementById('versie').value;
     var textvalue = "changes for " + appname + " version " + version;

    document.getElementById("notess_"+appId).value = textvalue;
}
```

i think that is what you need

Comment: well first of all, it was indeed one thing that the id needs to be unique. totally forget about that one. i think now i am at least  working in the good direction, but it doesnt work yet. first it only worked at the first form but now it doesnt do anything..